# NGINX: Disk write spike and/or not enough workers error from sudden surge in traffic causing 500 errors

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have been trying to diagnose an issue we have on our production servers. We have a server running NGINX as a load balancer which splits requests between four application servers. At least a few times throughout the day while testing the site we get 500 errors that only last for a few seconds.

Looking through the error logs and access logs, as well as graphs on new relic and our hosting service I have noticed a few things...

A few times a day there are sudden and massive jumps in disk write on the load balancer. I'm pretty sure this is due to so many requests being written to the access log in a short period of time (yesterday it was over 300 MB, most of which came in a very short period of time)... It's almost as if a bunch of requests are being blocked, piled up and then spit out simultaneously.

Also, once in a while I get a "768 worker connections is not enough..." in the error logs. I'm guessing I just need to raise this limit, but I'm not sure by how much, or how I can find the max that will work.

I'm not sure if these two issues are connected, or if either one is causing our random 500 errors.

Any insight or advice on further diagnosis would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can set up monitoring like Munin on it, and plot the amount of nginx connections? Setting up the munin host is a bit of work, but when installing the plugins in Ubuntu based servers, it auto detects the services you have and will enable the nginx plugin automatically, provided your nginx status command works.

Comment: Also might want to plot the average connection age and the activity on the app servers. It's possible that your app side is closing a bunch of connections simultaneously, causing connection finishes on the load balancer. I've seen this with something as simple as a database rowlock suddenly freeing and the resulting cache flush allowed >100 connections to finish.

Depending on how much ram you're willing to throw at the problem, you can probably go up to 3-4k safely. Around 4k, you'll need to play with maxfds on many systems.

Also, what is causing the access request spike? Sounds scheduled.